# mvn clean install don´t work without sudo

Tags: maven, ubuntu, permissions, installation, sudo

I have an strange problem, I have a project configured with maven, when I execute: *mvn clean install* I get this error:

```
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------- 
---------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------- 
---------
[INFO] Total time: 4.637 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-19T22:21:24-03:00
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------- 
---------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven- 
plugin:2.3:wsimport (wsimport-XXXXXXXXX-generate) on project 
XXXXXXXXXX: 
Mojo failed - check output -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with 
the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]    
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionExceptio
n
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with 
the command
```

- but when I execute *sudo mvn clean install* it work perfectly. Why do I need to execute with *sudo*
- I´m running over Ubuntu 16.04, maven 3.5.3 and  java 1.7.0_95

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: To get more logs and details try running with -e and -X parameters

Comment: Mojo plugin has failed as we see from the current logs. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

## For Linux Users

### What caused the problem:

- `sudo mvn clean install` on base pom.xml - linking all sub-projects to the **root** user

### How I  fixed the problem:

- Checked that all target folders belonged to the root user through `ls -al * | grep target`
- On the main project folder, where the base pom.xml is run:

  - `sudo chown -R username:username .`
  - Alternatively: `sudo chown -R username:username /home/username/path/to/project`